# Why does the method List.Add isn't working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game developed with unity, this is the code of a button. It should take the public List of the script "BoardScript" and add a number to this list, but, for some reason it isn't working.
I have checked that the Button click is working (as you can see, in the code the debug.log yes prints), but clicking it is not adding the number to my list.
In the "BoardScript" I added some numbers just to try, and the value adds to the list successfully, so, I guess that the error is somewhere in this script, but I can't figure what can be wrong.
Can you please help me?

```
   private Button B;
    void Start()
    {
        B = GetComponent<Button>();
        B.onClick.AddListener(Clicker);
    }
    void Clicker()
    {
        BoardScript boardScript = new BoardScript();
        int Two = 2;
        boardScript.UserList.Add(Two);
        Debug.Log("Added);
    }
    // Update is called once
```

**EDIT**
I almost forgot to tell a detail. I have write Debug.Log(UserList.Count) and The value is 1, even if I added 1 several times as the button script suggests (Its the same script but with different object).
So, As Steve Said This is the BoardScript code, it is a little long.

```
private int[] PreList = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    private List<int> ButtonList = new List<int>();
    public List<int> UserList = new List<int>();
    private System.Random Rnd = new System.Random();
    public List<int> EndList = new List<int>();

    void Randomizer()
    {
        PreList = PreList.OrderBy(C => Rnd.Next()).ToArray();
        foreach (var item in PreList)
        {
            Debug.Log(item.ToString());
            if (item == 1)
            {
                OneMethod();
            }
            if (item == 2)
            {
                TwoMethod();

            }
            if (item == 3)
            {
                ThreeMethod();

            }
            if (item == 4)
            {
                FourMethod();

            }
            if (item == 5)
            {
                FiveMethod();

            }
            if (item == 6)
            {
                SixMethod();

            }
            if (item == 7)
            {
                SevenMethod();

            }
            if (item == 8)
            {
                EightMethod();

            }
            if (item == 9)
            {
                NineMethod();

            }
        }
        EndList = PreList.ToList();
    }
     void  OneMethod()
     {
        //yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        ButtonList.Add(1);

     }
    void TwoMethod()
    {
        ButtonList.Add(2);

    }
    void ThreeMethod()
    {
        ButtonList.Add(3);

    }
    void FourMethod()
    {
        ButtonList.Add(4);

    }
    void  FiveMethod()
    {
        ButtonList.Add(5);

    }
    void SixMethod()
    {
        ButtonList.Add(6);

    }
    void SevenMethod()
    {
        ButtonList.Add(7);
    }
    void EightMethod()
    {
        ButtonList.Add(8);

    }
    void NineMethod()
    {
        ButtonList.Add(9);
    }
    void Start ()
    {
        Randomizer();
        string[] the_array = ButtonList.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray();
        string OrderString = string.Join(", ", the_array);
        GameObject.Find("Order").GetComponent<Text>().text = OrderString;
        UserList.Add(1);
        UserList.Add(5);

    }
    IEnumerator Waiter()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        string[] the_array = UserList.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray();
        string OrderString = string.Join(", ", the_array);
        Debug.Log(OrderString);
        if (UserList.Count == 8)
        {
            if (UserList == ButtonList)
            {
                //Sound
                BehaviourModel B = new BehaviourModel();
                B.Counter++;
                if (B.Counter < 10)
                {
                    SceneManager.LoadScene(B.SceneArray[B.Counter]);
                }
                else if (B.Counter > 10)
                {
                    SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenuScene");
                }
            }
            else if (UserList != ButtonList)
            {
                UserList.Clear();
                Debug.Log("Fail");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your `BoardScript` script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you click the button you create a new instance of `BoardScript`. You should store the `boardScript` variable as a variable in your class or separate component to ensure the data will persist.

Comment: What do you mean with store BoardScript as a variable in my class? Do you mean like doing it private up in my class?, like I did it with the Button B?

Comment: Yes @PazlGame you have it as a **local variable** and its scope is restricted to that one method/function. if you move the declaration of the `BoardScript` outside the method but still within the class its scope is restricted to the class - we call that a **member or private variable** - so it will live between button clicks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do either create only one Instance, like:

```
private Button B;
BoardScript boardScript = new BoardScript();
```

then in your `void Clicker()` method:
add item to UserList.

**Or:**
You can create a static variable in your BoardScript class and check for null. If its null, then create a new instance else return an old instance.

The following code will help:

```
private static BoardScript _uniqueBoardScript;

 private BoardScript()
 {}

 public static BoardScript GetInstance()
 {
     if(_uniqueBoardScript==null)
     { 
         _uniqueBoardScript = new BoardScript();
     }
     return _uniqueBoardScript;
 }
```

and from your `void Clicker()`

```
{
    BoardScript boardScript = BoardScript.GetInstance();
    int Two = 2;
    boardScript.UserList.Add(Two);
    Debug.Log("Added);
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code boardscript = BoardScript.GetInstance(); but I don't get the method GetInstance();

Comment: in your void Clicker() method, you are creating a new instance of BoardScript which will wipe off the previous values of its member variables

Comment: By having a private constructor and using static variable, only instance of the class can be created (its like a singleton pattern)..